# If field empty set border to red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After click on button set border around the text field to red.

```
Name <input type="text" class="one" id="name"> 
<input type="button" value="OK" >
```

I know the style for border is

```
.one {
border-style:solid;
border-color:#0000ff;
}
```

I want to set border to red if this field name is empty after i click on button.
Can i make it with php only or i must use java script and event on click ??

Comment: my suggestion is just use a clientside validation library for that, it will do the heavy lifting for you (check if its empty, adds color red on wrong form inputs, etc.). [sample (if you want to use jquery)](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text element to change color dynamically (at run time) you need to use Javascript. If you want the element to change color as a result of a form action (postback) then you can alter the markup generated by the postback from PHP. But based on your question and the fact that this is 2014 you're probably looking for the JS solution.

You can use PHP to generate the JavaScript script but cannot use PHP to handle the mouse click event.

To do so, using pure Javascript, you would write something like:

```
 <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="document.getElementById('name').className = 'one'; ">
```

Comment: First i need to check if the field is empty if so then i need to add the class "one" i used event onclick before but it would be usefull to have combined code example html+php+js .. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript for that. You should just call a JavaScript function upon click to the text box and add class when the button is clicked hence applying CSS when class is added by JavaScript.
All you have to do in function is check if the text box is empty is so add class else skip.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with just PHP. You need to change your form code to something like

```
<form method = "POST" action = "this.php">
Name <input type="text" class="one" id="name"> 
<input type="submit" value="OK" >
</form>
```

Then the page is reloaded. Before the form elements are created you go through an if statement, whether or not the forms should be red. If the forms have data in them (look at the isset function), and the data is in a format you request, then recreate the form with the old input. If the input is invalid, give it a red border.

It's probably simpler to use javascript though.

EDIT: It gets kind of ugly. I cant test PHP right now, but this HTML seems to work:

```
<form method = "POST">
<div class = "somediv">
    <input type="text" class="one" id="name" name = "aname"/> 
    <input type="button" value="OK" />
</div>

<div class = "anotherdiv">
    <input type="text" class="one" id="name" name = "anothername"/> 
    <input type="button" value="OK" />   
</div>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" name ="OK"/>
</form>
```

Comment: My page have 10 hidden div's . Each one of them show's on button click one by one (per click ). After all i click on last which is submit type and send all those data to mail. so i prob can't use any action type or your example. Do you have any simple code examlpe for my problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: It's pretty simple. Just put the form tags around you divs, so that all controls are within it. The code will look ugly, and be hard to read, but not impossible. (this is without javascript still).

Answer (score 0):

for changing textbox properties by clicking on a button, you need to use the Javascript.
Add an event to the button, so we can the check the value of the textbox.

**Html**

```
Name : <input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button" value="OK" onclick="checkVal()">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checkVal() {
 var name = document.getElementById("name"), value = name.value;
 var classes = name.className;    
 if (value.replace(/\s/g, "") === "") {
   name.className = classes+" one";
 }
 else {
   if (classes.indexOf("one") !== -1) {name.className = classes.repalce(/one/g, '')}
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi is there any way i can redesign this function so i can use multiple times by call on difference places and different ID ?  to be like function checkVal(IDtotest) ??? Also i'm newb can i add the html part inside javascript   `code` function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
//How can i add this html part ? 
        <div id="7" style="display: block;">
    }
}`code`

Comment: you can pass the id and classname to the function. checkVal(id, classname){..} and replace the static "name" with id and "one" with classname. change the calling function onclick="checkVal('name','one')". you can add html content using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can suggest to you is using `required="required"` in your `text-field`.

Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="textFieldName" required="required" placeholder="sampleValue" />
```

In that case, when the form is submitted and that field is required, the browser will recognized that it is empty and will automatically set its border to red and says this field is required if you are using Firefox. On Chrome otherwise, it will pop-up a message saying this field is required.

Give it a try and good luck!